# Looping through download.file() in R causes timeout

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a pipeline for downloading multiple files, unzipping and merging them in the end but I get a timeout error at the step of the download using base R function `download.file`.

Below is my code snippet

```
files %>% 
  paste0(url, .) %>% 
  map(download.file(., destfile = gsub("^.*/", "", .)))
```

First comes the base url and the file name is extracted for later use.
The above code returns the following

```
Warning messages:
1: In download.file(., destfile = gsub("^.*/", "", .)) :
  URL 'https://example.com/files/file1.csv.gz': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached
2: In download.file(., destfile = gsub("^.*/", "", .)) :
  URL 'https://example.com/files/file2.csv.gz': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached
3: In download.file(., destfile = gsub("^.*/", "", .)) :
  some files were not downloaded
```

From what  I understand the problem seems to be that a connection is established to download ALL the files at the same time. Beyond that, any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can set `options(timeout = 300)`, it's unlikely that `map()` is the issue, try the 3 files independently

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it's actually a lot more than 3 files that's why I'm looking for a similar solution.

Comment: Still you should try if it works with a single file outside of the map call, and try to copy this address in your browser and see if its valid.

Comment: So far it works fine with a single file by manually entering the arguments (URL and destfile).

Comment: Weird, assuming you tried precisely a file that triggered the warning. maybe try wrapping download.file in `purrr::slowly()`